# Generating new unique uuid4 in Django for each object of Factory class

Tags: python, django, factory-boy

I have a Model Sector which has a id field (pk) which is UUID4 type.
I am trying to populate that table(Sector Model) using faker and factory_boy.

But,

```
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(46f0cf58-7e63-4d0b-9dff-e157261562d2) already exists.
```

This is the error I am getting.

Is it possible that the error is due to the fact that everytime I am creating SectorFactory objects (which is in a different django app) and the seed gets reset to some previous number causing the uuid to repeat?

Please suggest some ways as to how I shall get unique uuid for each Factory object?

SectorFactory class

```
import uuid
from factory.django import DjangoModelFactory
from factory.faker import Faker
from factory import Sequence


class SectorFactory(DjangoModelFactory): 
    id = uuid.uuid4()
    name = Sequence(lambda n: f'Sector-{n}')

    class Meta:
        model = 'user.Sector'
        django_get_or_create = ['name']
```

Class Sector

```
class Sector(models.Model):
    id      = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default = uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name    = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'sector'
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint('name', name = 'unique_sector_name')
        ]
```

The script which creates the custom command to create SectorFactory objects.

```
from types import NoneType
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from user.factories import SectorFactory

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Generate fake data and seed the models with them.'

    
    def add_arguments(self, parser) -> None:
        parser.add_argument( '--amount', type=int, help='The amount of fake objects to create.' )

    def _generate_sectors(self, amount):
        for _ in range(amount):
            SectorFactory()
    
    def handle(self, *args, **options) :

        amount = options['amount']
        if(type(amount) == NoneType): amount = 10
        
        self._generate_sectors(amount)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just use like this:

```py
class SectorFactory(DjangoModelFactory): 
    id = Faker('uuid4')
    name = Sequence(lambda n: f'Sector-{n}')

    class Meta:
        model = 'user.Sector'
        django_get_or_create = ['name']
```